# 5 year old child causing problems at school

Tags: discipline, primary-schooler, school

My son is 5 years of age. When he started school he was quite calm at the beginning. But after summer holidays he has become very restless. He has become aggressive and is not listening to his teachers. He is running around untie corridors, throwing things around, tearing books, pushing other kids, not doing his school work, distracting the class, etc. I can't figure out what to do. How can I deal with this?

Comment: I have made a few edits to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Can you sit in class a couple of days and see what's happening, how his behavior kicks off?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that my son's behavior worsens after vacation. I find that the following helps to get it better:

1. Schedule - get him in bed on time
2. No electronics and TV
3. A lot of time outside to get his energy out
4. Talking to him about his behavior
5. May be get some suggestions from his teacher